# Rule: Auto Menu link for child via entity reference

Tags: 7, entities, rules, navigation

I have child nodes which are assigned to the entity reference of the parents. I want to create a rule which assigns the child node menu items to the parent node menu link. I have many parent nodes, so the rule should be dynamic for every category (parent).

I created a rule with the following settings.

```
Event: After saving new content of type
Conditions: Nothing
Action: Create a menu item for node
```

In the 'Action' I do not know which "Data selector" to choose from. I think that I must choose my entity reference field "node:field-reference:menu-link:mlid", but it does not work. I do not know what the Data selector should be. It is stated that the data type should be text, but "node:field-reference:menu-link:title" or "node:field-reference:menu-link:url" do not work either.
Apart from that I am using the default settings of the action.

For testing purpose: The rule works when I manually set a menu parent item via drop down, but that is not dynamic for every category.

How can I create the rule to get a menu link for the child nodes via entity reference?